# Create a class extending another class at runtime in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, react-apollo

I have the following:

```
class PeopleByNameQueryComponent extends Query<FindPeopleByNameQuery, FindPeopleByNameQueryVariables> { }


export const PeopleByNameQuery = (props: any) => {
    const { children, ...otherProps } = props;
    return <PeopleByNameQueryComponent query={FIND_PEOPLE_QUERY} variables={props.variables} {...otherProps}>
...
    </PeopleByNameQueryComponent>;
}
```

I'd like to reduce the code to something like:

```
export const PeopleByNameQuery = (props: any) => {
    const { children, ...otherProps } = props;

    const ClassToUse = GenericQueryClass extends Query<props.FindQuery, props.QueryVariables> { }

    return <ClassToUse query={FIND_PEOPLE_QUERY} variables={props.variables} {...otherProps}>
    </ClassToUse>;
}
```

I'm not too sure if this is possible, the end goal is to reduce the amount of code being written to accomplish the same thing, there will be a lot of queries.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: what's the purpose of inheriting from a class without adding any code/value to that new class? Why don't you just use Query?

Comment: @Thomas It's how to build query components using Apollo, if there's another way to do it I'd love to know :)

Comment: I have no experience with Apollo, but when I open their [Docs on that topic](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#basic), I don't read anything about inheritance. So, just use their `Query`-component. And btw. it is still unclear what your question is.